# Running Haskell HXT outside of IO?

Tags: haskell, hxt

All the examples I've seen so far using the Haskell XML toolkit, HXT, uses `runX` to execute the parser. `runX` runs inside the IO monad. Is there a way of using this XML parser outside of IO? Seems to be a pure operation to me, don't understand why I'm forced to be inside IO.

Comment: A quick glance makes it look to me like `runX` reads the XML file and is thus impure IO.

Comment: I think HXT's parser is an 'online' parser i.e. it doesn't need to read the whole input to start producing output. The upside of this is that (in principle at least) it can run with a constant memory footprint, the downside is that it has to read "chunks" of the input on demand so must be in IO.

Comment: But couldn't this easily be solved using lazy IO? For example, in order to get high-performance XML-parsing, right now I use Hexpat (for ByteStrings, and lazy SAX-parsing.) and polyparse (Poly.Lazy.) I'm getting constant memory footprints, fast processing, and *all* the parsing is done in pure functions!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use HXT's [`xread`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/8.5.2/doc/html/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-ReadDocument.html#v:xread) along with [`runLA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/8.5.2/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ListArrow.html) to parse an XML string outside of `IO`.

`xread` has the following type:

```
xread :: ArrowXml a => a String XmlTree
```

This means you can compose it with any arrow of type `(ArrowXml a) => a XmlTree Whatever` to get an `a String Whatever`.

`runLA` is like `runX`, but for things of type `LA`:

```
runLA :: LA a b -> a -> [b]
```

`LA` is an instance of `ArrowXml`.

To put this all together, the following version of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897283/haskell-hxt-for-extracting-a-list-of-values/3897533#3897533) to your previous question uses HXT to parse a string containing well-formed XML without any `IO` involved:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
module Main where

import qualified Data.Map as M
import Text.XML.HXT.Arrow

classes :: (ArrowXml a) => a XmlTree (M.Map String String)
classes = listA (divs >>> pairs) >>> arr M.fromList
  where
    divs = getChildren >>> hasName "div"
    pairs = proc div -> do
      cls <- getAttrValue "class" -< div
      val <- deep getText         -< div
      returnA -< (cls, val)

getValues :: (ArrowXml a) => [String] -> a XmlTree (String, Maybe String)
getValues cs = classes >>> arr (zip cs . lookupValues cs) >>> unlistA
  where lookupValues cs m = map (flip M.lookup m) cs

xml = "<div><div class='c1'>a</div><div class='c2'>b</div>\
      \<div class='c3'>123</div><div class='c4'>234</div></div>"

values :: [(String, Maybe String)]
values = runLA (xread >>> getValues ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"]) xml

main = print values
```

`classes` and `getValues` are similar to the previous version, with a few minor changes to suit the expected input and output. The main difference is that here we use `xread` and `runLA` instead of `readString` and `runX`.

It would be nice to be able to read something like a lazy `ByteString` in a similar manner, but as far as I know this isn't currently possible with HXT.

---

A couple of other things: you *can* parse strings in this way without `IO`, but it's probably better to use `runX` whenever you can: it gives you more control over the configuration of the parser, error messages, etc.

Also: I tried to make the code in the example straightforward and easy to extend, but the combinators in [`Control.Arrow`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Arrow.html) and [`Control.Arrow.ArrowList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.0.0/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html) make it possible to work with arrows much more concisely if you like. The following is an equivalent definition of `classes`, for example:

```
classes = (getChildren >>> hasName "div" >>> pairs) >. M.fromList
  where pairs = getAttrValue "class" &&& deep getText
```

Comment: Hi Travis. That's great. Your help is very useful in my attempt to come to grips with HXT.

Answer (score 1):

Travis Brown's answer was very helpful. I just want to add my own solution here, which I think is a bit more general (using the same functions, just ignoring the problem-specific issues).

I was previously unpickling with:

```hs
upIO      :: XmlPickler a => String -> IO [a]
upIO str   = runX $ readString [] str >>> arrL (maybeToList . unpickleDoc xpickle)
```

which I was able to change to this:

```hs
upPure    :: XmlPickler a => String -> [a]
upPure str = runLA (xreadDoc >>> arrL (maybeToList . unpickleDoc xpickle)) str
```

I completely agree with him that doing this gives you less control over the configuration of the parser etc, which is unfortunate.