# Collapse arrow to list

Tags: xml, haskell, arrows, hxt

I'm having some problems with [HXT](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~si/HXmlToolbox/), though I suspect it's just something I'm missing about arrows.

I have an XML structure like

```
<str name="field1">value</str>
<lst name="field2"><str>value2</str><str>value3</str></lst>
```

And internal structure like

```
data XmlData = XmlStr String | XmlList XmlData
```

Is there a way to collect elements at a step in an arrow?

```
getXmlData :: IOSArrow XmlTree (String, XmlData)
getXmlData = (getAttrl >>> getChildren >>> getText) &&& 
      ((filterByType "str" >>> getText >>> arr (\x -> XmlStr x))
      <+> (filterByType "lst" >>> getXmlData))
  where filterByType t = isElem >>> hasName t >>> getChildren
```

The recursive call to getXmlData needs to collect it's answer and wrap in an XmlList constructor, but I don't know how to collect terms.  Currently I'm accomplishing this with some post processing on the output (collecting on the same name), but I would like a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can use `listA` from [`Control.Arrow.ArrowList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/9.0.0/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html) to do this. It has type `(ArrowList a) => a b c -> a b [c]` and is a

> combinator for converting an arrow
>   into a determinstic version with all
>   results collected in a single element
>   list.

(See my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897283/haskell-hxt-for-extracting-a-list-of-values/3897533#3897533) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901492/running-haskell-hxt-outside-of-io/3901775#3901775) for a concrete example.)

In this specific case you can use the `>.` combinator with the `XmlList` constructor as its second argument to accomplish the same thing more concisely.

Comment: >. worked when I moved the getChildren call out of the helper and added some parenthesis.  I was curious about the usage for listA but couldn't find an example with it as part of a pipeline.  Could you provide a solution with listA?

Comment: @amccausl: In the first answer linked above we have an non-deterministic arrow with type `a XmlTree (String, String)` and we want to use it with `arr Data.Map.fromList` (of type `a [(String, String)] (M.Map String String)`) to fill a map. `listA` lets us make the types of the arrows match up so that they can be composed.